# call different class method within same class

Tags: python

Trying to get better at OOP in Python, and trying to lose weight. Wanted to see if I could output a bodyfat % change for each pound of body fat lost.

Want to call `cal_bf()` in `lbs_chart()`, but can't seem to do it. Maybe it is because I am relying on the `__init__` for `cal_bf()`?

The other answers for a similar question were too confusing for me.

Also, having some trouble indenting my methods in the question box, sorry.

```
class Bodyweight():
    
    def __init__(self, total_weight, muscle_lbs=None, fat_lbs=None):
        self.total_weight = total_weight
        self.muscle_lbs = muscle_lbs
        self.fat_lbs = fat_lbs


    def cal_bf(self):
        if self.muscle_lbs is None:
            bf_perc = self.fat_lbs / self.total_weight * 100
            return f"Body fat percentage is: {bf_perc: .2f}%"
        else:
            bf_perc = 1 - self.fat_lbs / self.total_weight * 100
            return f"Body fat percentage is: {bf_perc: .2f}%"

    def lbs_charts(self):
        self.fat_lbs = self.fat_lbs
        while self.fat_lbs > 20:
                self.total_weight -= 1
                self.fat_lbs -= 1
                Bodyweight.cal_bf(self)

b = Bodyweight(total_weight=200, fat_lbs=55)
chart = b.lbs_charts()
    
print(chart)
```

Comment: Change `Bodyweight.cal_bf(self)` to `self.cal_bf()`.

Comment: Simply: self.cal_bf()

Comment: 2 other notes: `self.fat_lbs = self.fat_lbs` doesn't really do anything. And `chart = b.lbs_charts()` but `lbs_charts` does  not `return` anything.

Comment: I suggest you read more about the difference between a class and instances of a class to understand @jfaccioni's suggestion.

Comment: And, `bf_perc = 1 - self.fat_lbs / self.total_weight * 100` I _think_ you want parentheses here. `bf_perc = (1 - self.fat_lbs / self.total_weight) * 100` See [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Ok. I will

Comment: Man, lots of mistakes. Thanks for the help. @JohnnyMopp why doesn't lbs_charts() calling self.cal_bf(self) use cal_bf()'s return methods? That is why I didn't put a return method there, assumed it would use cal_bf()'s return method

Comment: Even though `cal_bf` has a `return`, `lbs_charts` completely ignores it. You would need something like `return self.cal_bf()` - but that would end the `while` loop so it is unclear what that function should return.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. Thanks. Back to the drawing board, then.